# Coded UI Test Project Customization

Tags: testing

With a class like this one, right clicking inside the test method should give you a "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" -> "Use Coded UI Test Builder" option. It will still minimize Visual Studio, but it shouldn't create a new test method. There is also a keyboard shortcut:CTRL+\,CTRL+C

```
[CodedUITest] public class MyUITests
{
 public MyUITests()
{
}

[TestMethod]
public void StartMyTest()
{
    //right click in here to get the context menu option
}
}
```

I did,but my question is

How to get generated code when I click on "Add and Generate" button?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't create new test method. an UIMap - Coded UI Test Builder small window should appear.
You will need to start recording and then clicking on generate code.